# Synchronizing two comboboxes bound to the same collection and to the same selected item

Tags: c#, mvvm, combobox, selecteditem, selectedvalue

I have two comboboxes to represent a customer code and a customer name. Both are bound to the same collection of objects and to the same `SelectedItem`. I want to update the customer name when I select a customer code and vice versa.

I am using C# with the MVVM pattern. I have tried all the combination of `SelectedItem` and `SelectedValue` with selectedvaluepath but nothing seems to work.

These are my two combo boxes:

```
<ComboBox Name="CmbStockUnitCustomerCode" ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerCodeDtos}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Code" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCustomer, Mode=TwoWay}" 
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"></ComboBox>

<ComboBox Name="CmbStockUnitCustomerName" ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerCodeDtos}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCustomer, Mode=TwoWay}" 
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"></ComboBox>
```

And these are the bound objects:

```
public CustomerDto SelectedCustomer
{
    get => _selectedcustomer;
    set
    {
        _selectedcustomer = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedCustomer");
    }
}

public class CustomerDto
{
    public short Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public CustomerDto(short code, string name)
    {
        this.Code = code;
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
public ObservableCollection<CustomerDto> CustomerCodeDtos
{
    get => _databaseService.GetAllCustomers();
}
```

When I update one of the comboboxes, I expect the other one to update to the corresponding value in the object CustomerDto, but nothing happens.

Comment: Can you post the code for the CustomerCodeDtos collection property too, just for completeness.

Comment: the CustomerCodeDtos is a simple ObservableCollection of CustomerDto that i get and populate from database.

Comment: There's your problem. You're getting a new collection every time. Get the collection once, store it in an instance variable and reference that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're recreating your collection every time you reference it, so SelectedItem is referencing a different object. In effect, your two combo boxes are using different collections as ItemsSources. Change the code to

```
public ObservableCollection<CustomerDto> CustomerCodeDtos
{
    get 
    { 
       if(_customerCodes==null)
       {
          _customerCodes = _databaseService.GetAllCustomers();
       }
       return _customerCodes;
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! I was not expecting to be that kind of problem! Thx!